# loop through table tr and retrieve value from second td

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML table:

```
<table id="review-total">
     <tbody><tr class="wlp">
            <td class="left-cell">WLP Total</td>
            <td>199.00</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="tax">
            <td class="left-cell">GST</td>
            <td>19.90</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="net">
        <td class="left-cell">Order Total</td>
        <td class="net-price">$218.90</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to loop through this table and retrieve the values i.e

199.00, 19.90 and $218.90 I have the following code:

```
var reviewTotal = document.getElementById('review-total');
for (var i = 1; i < reviewTotal.rows.length; i++) {
  if (reviewTotal.rows[i].cells.length) {
     wlpTotal = (reviewTotal.rows[i].cells[1].textContent.trim());
     gstAmount = (reviewTotal.rows[i].cells[3].textContent.trim());
     totalOrderAmount = (reviewTotal.rows[i].cells[5].textContent.trim());
  }
}
```

I'm having a small issue trying to retrieve those values specified above, at present the error I get is textContent is undefined.

Can someone show me how I should go about retrieving those values, unfortunately I'm not strong in Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 rows and each row has only 2 cells. The 3 and 5 indices are `undefined` and `undefined` doesn't have `.textContent` property.

If you want to store the values by using specific variable names, you remove the loop and select the target elements manually:

```
var wlpTotal = reviewTotal.rows[0].cells[1].textContent.trim();
var gstAmount = reviewTotal.rows[1].cells[1].textContent.trim();
var totalOrderAmount = reviewTotal.rows[2].cells[1].textContent.trim();
```

If you want to store the values in an array, you can code:

```
var values = [].map.call(reviewTotal.rows, function(row) {
   return row.cells[1].textContent.trim();
});
```

By using ES2015's [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) you can also extract the array's elements:

```
var [wlpTotal, gstAmount, totalOrderAmount] = values;
```

Answer (score 0):

First:the index start the 0 either row or cell.
Secend:get value in the tag to use innerText or innerHTML ,The code following:

```
var reviewTotal = document.getElementById('review-total');
    for (var i = 0; i < reviewTotal.rows.length; i++) 
    {
        if (reviewTotal.rows[i].cells.length>1) 
        {
            wlpTotal = (reviewTotal.rows[i].cells[1].innerText);
        }
    }
```